# Print Out if a Value Exist in for loop Output in R

Tags: r, for-loop, search

I want `R` to check and print out the line that contains `0.2` if it exists in my output, else print `not available`

```
seed_out <- c(96148,96182,96192,96198,96241,96243,96258,96265,96308,96317,96357,96434,96547,96552,96566,96570,96613,96654,96686,96715,96721,96744,96757,96772,96842,96844,96852,96889,96894,96926,96971,97058,97076,97100,97117,97131,97156,97161,97162,97199,97255,97349,97382,97383,97400,97439,97440,97549,97550,97555,97587,97595,97604,97608,97645,97723,97828,97847,97874,97904,97910,97913,97953,97966,97984,98012,98020,98038,98052,98062,98078,98104,98112,98181,98182,98190,98253,98262,98263,98264,98390,98457,98483,98503,98512,98525,98556,98576,98599,98603,98630,98631,98648,98666,98668,98671,98733,98756,98776,98782,98784,98821,98833,98852,98873,98882,98959,99007,99013,99044,99133,99161,99198,99222,99227,99250,99254,99301,99344,99422,99447,99515,99522,99543,99566,99605,99607,99617,99627,99716,99734,99746,99763,99780,99782,99795,99807,99821,99864,99883,99884)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
arima_order_results = data.frame()
for (my_seed in seed_out){
  set.seed(my_seed)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 20, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
  arr <- as.data.frame(t(ar2$coef))
  arr <- cbind(data.frame(seed=my_seed),arr)
  print(arr)
  arima_order_results = bind_rows(arima_order_results,arr)
  write.csv(my_seed, paste0(arr, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

The output of the above `for loop` looks like this:

```
  #seed      ar1
#1 2381 0.631023
  #seed       ar1
#1 2385 0.5262573
  #seed        ar1  intercept
#1 2447 -0.3721784 -0.2110689
  #seed       ar1
#1 2470 0.5961704
  #seed       ar1
#1 2505 0.4839624
  #seed       ar1
#1 2519 0.6552797
  #seed       ar1
#1 2525 0.4676456
  #seed     ar1
#1 2529 0.60793
  #seed       ar1
#1 2545 0.4512717
```

I am interested in **searching and for `0.2...`** in the `third` column`where`ar1`is and **printing its whole row**, such that if there is no` 0.2...`the response should be`not available`. the` ...`means any number may follow the`0.2`but it must start with`0.2`

I have the real job in thousands of rows and will want `R` to do the searching for me instead of doing it manually that is prone to mistake of oversight.

Comment: No, the column before the intercept

Comment: You meant for the second column i.e. 'ar1' should have only values that start with `0.2`

Comment: Yes, the column with ar1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use `substr` and compare with `==` for `"0.2"`

```
arima_order_results = data.frame()
for (my_seed in seed_out){
  set.seed(my_seed)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 20, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
  arr <- as.data.frame(t(ar2$coef))
  if(substr(as.character(arr[1]), 1, 3) == "0.2") {
    
    arr <- cbind(data.frame(seed=my_seed),arr)
    print(arr)
  
  arima_order_results = bind_rows(arima_order_results,arr)
    # write.csv(my_seed, paste0(arr, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
    
    }
}
```

-testing with `0.4`

```
 arima_order_results = data.frame()
 for (my_seed in seed_out){
   set.seed(my_seed)
   ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 20, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
   ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
   arr <- as.data.frame(t(ar2$coef))
   if(substr(as.character(arr[1]), 1, 3) == "0.4") {
    arr <- cbind(data.frame(seed=my_seed),arr)
    print(arr)
    
   arima_order_results = bind_rows(arima_order_results, arr)
    # write.csv(my_seed, paste0(arr, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
    
    } else print("NOT AVAILABLE")
 }
  



#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#   seed       ar1
#1 96198 0.4701125
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#   seed       ar1
#1 96258 0.4656755
#   seed       ar1
#1 96265 0.4689137
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#   seed       ar1
#1 96566 0.4904535
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#   seed       ar1
#1 96721 0.4927641
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#   seed       ar1
#1 96757 0.4803991
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
#[1] "NOT AVAILABLE"
# ...
```

Comment: It does not print out anything

Comment: I did use it to search for`0.4512717` which is the last `ar1` value but it doe not print out anything

Comment: @DanielJames In the code, it will `print` only if the `ar1` value starts with `0.2`

Comment: please show your search output let me see where the difference is for I have searched for the `0.2` and got no print-out

Comment: @DanielJames With those seed you provided, I didn't get any value that is 0.2.  I was thinking that you have a larger vector on which you may find it

Comment: @DanielJames if it is 0.4, I am getting a lot

Comment: Please, let it print out `NOT AVAILABLE` if what one search for can not be found

Comment: @DanielJames if it is not true, then you need an `else` statement with `print("NOT AVAILABLE")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226012/discussion-between-daniel-james-and-akrun).